# Json array inside json array parsing

Tags: json

**There is a json array called records , Inside records there is another array called records too , How can we parse this.**

Please find the json format below.

**There is a json array called records , Inside records there is another array called records too , How can we parse this.**

Please find the json format below.

```
{
   "totalSize":17,
   "done":true,
   "records":[
      {
         "attributes":{
            "type":"Order",
            "url":"/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/Order/8011m0000008c8WAAQ"
         },
         "Id":"8011m0000008c8WAAQ",
         "DocumentType__c":null,
         "Orderno__c":null,
         "BiitoCustomerNo__c":null,
         "SelltoCustomerNo__c":null,
         "OrderDate__c":null,
         "PostingDate__c":null,
         "DocumentDate__c":null,
         "LocationCode__c":null,
         "Narration__c":null,
         "OrderCode__c":"Order - 000013",
         "OrderItems":null
      },
      {
         "Id":"8011m0000008c0SAAQ",
         "DocumentType__c":null,
         "Orderno__c":null,
         "BiitoCustomerNo__c":null,
         "SelltoCustomerNo__c":null,
         "OrderDate__c":null,
         "PostingDate__c":null,
         "DocumentDate__c":null,
         "LocationCode__c":null,
         "Narration__c":null,
         "OrderCode__c":"Order - 000008",
         "OrderItems":{
            "totalSize":2,
            "done":true,
            "records":[
               {
                  "attributes":{
                     "type":"OrderItem",
                     "url":"/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/OrderItem/8021m000000DBirAAG"
                  },
                  "Id":"8021m000000DBirAAG",
                  "Document_Type__c":null,
                  "Sell_to_Customer_No__c":null,
                  "Item_Code__c":"OP-000004",
                  "Variant_Code__c":null,
                  "Location_Code__c":null,
                  "Quantity":2,
                  "Sales_Quantity__c":null,
                  "Shipment_Date__c":null
               },
               {
                  "attributes":{
                     "type":"OrderItem",
                     "url":"/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/OrderItem/8021m000000DBiqAAG"
                  },
                  "Id":"8021m000000DBiqAAG",
                  "Document_Type__c":null,
                  "Sell_to_Customer_No__c":null,
                  "Item_Code__c":"OP-000003",
                  "Variant_Code__c":null,
                  "Location_Code__c":null,
                  "Quantity":2,
                  "Sales_Quantity__c":null,
                  "Shipment_Date__c":null
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Which programming-language?

Comment: @Melvin parsing in java

Answer (score 1):

This is a naive approach I can think of

```
@Test
void name() throws JsonProcessingException {
    String data = "{\n" +
            "  \"totalSize\": 17,\n" +
            "  \"done\": true,\n" +
            "  \"records\": [\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "      \"Id\": \"8011m0000008c8WAAQ\",\n" +
            "      \"OrderItems\": null\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "      \"Id\": \"8011m0000008c0SAAQ\",\n" +
            "      \"OrderItems\": {\n" +
            "        \"totalSize\": 2,\n" +
            "        \"done\": true,\n" +
            "        \"records\": [\n" +
            "          {\n" +
            "            \"Id\": \"8021m000000DBirAAG\",\n" +
            "            \"Shipment_Date__c\": null\n" +
            "          },\n" +
            "          {\n" +
            "            \"Id\": \"8021m000000DBiqAAG\",\n" +
            "            \"Shipment_Date__c\": null\n" +
            "          }\n" +
            "        ]\n" +
            "      }\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "  ]\n" +
            "}";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Example example = mapper.readValue(data, Example.class);
    String s = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(example);
    System.out.println(s);
}

static class Example {
    public int totalSize;
    public boolean done;
    @JsonProperty("records")
    public List<Record> records;
}

static class Record {
    public String Id;
    public OrderItems OrderItems;
}

static class OrderItems {
    public int totalSize;
    public boolean done;
    @JsonProperty("records")
    public List<NestedRecord> nestedRecords;
}

static class NestedRecord {
    public String Id;
    public Object Shipment_Date__c;
}
```

using `jackson` library.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.4</version>
</dependency>
```